# Numpy append not adding row to Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a method where it checks if we are at row 0.

If yes: it creates the Numpy array as that row.
If no: it appends the row to the Numpy array

```
def printStatement(row):  
    global newData
    if(count == 0):
        newData = np.array(row)

    else:
        print("Made it to second row")
        np.append(newData, row)
```

It does confirm that it made it to the else statement. But newData does not grow past the first row.

Is there something I need to specify when creating the array? All rows are the same shape.

***2D Array (Added for search engine)

Comment: Have you tried `np.array([row, row, row,...])`?

Comment: There are 23k+ rows.

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing the result, assign it to something. E.g. `newData = no.append(newData, row)`

Quoting https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html:

A copy of arr with values appended to axis. Note that append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled.

And by the way, prefer avoiding np.append unless really necessary.

Comment: What do i use instead?

Comment: prefer a list, convert  to an array once

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: All I'm saying is collect the rows in a list, then convert to array in one go.